# Where do I put my APK expansion file?

Tags: android, apk

I have 90MB of mp3 files that my media player app uses.  I want to upload my `.apk` to google play but since my app is over 50MB I have to put my mp3 files into a expansion file.  I have read the documentation here : http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html and I have created the expansion file like so ...

```
red@ubuntu:~/android/workspace/Album/res/raw$ zip -n .mp3 main.1.com.redcricket.Album.obb *mp3
```

... but the documentation does not say where this file belongs in the android project directory hierarchy.  Am I suppose to move the file `main.1.com.redcricket.Album.obb` to the `asset` directory?

Comment: The answer to this question can be found here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42000/error-with-adb-push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expansion files are stored and managed separately from your APK and therefore don't go into the assets folder at all. When you upload the application to Google Play (whether as a draft or publish it), it gives you the option of uploading the expansion files as well.

Comment: ok ... but I would like to be able to build and test my app before I jump right to uploading it to Google Play.  So I I don't put the obb file in the asset directory where do I put it so I can test my app?

Comment: The section on testing on that exact website you linked to has all the details, including the folder to manually put the file into: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing

Comment: The doc says, "For example, if your package name is com.example.android, you need to create the directory Android/obb/com.example.android/ on the shared storage space. (Plug in your test device to your computer to mount the shared storage and manually create this directory.)" but it does not say what working directory I need to be in to when I create that directory.

Comment: The Storage Location section states that the directory is <shared-storage>/Android/obb/<package-name>/ where <shared-storage> is the path to the shared storage space, available from getExternalStorageDirectory(): http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#StorageLocation

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I had to fix eclipse ... took me over an hour.  Gotta get some sleep now

Comment: Looks like `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns `/mnt/sdcard` so I guess that is where my App will look for the APK expansion file on my phone, after the App is installed.  I need to know where I put my APK expansion file so that eclipse will upload to my phone when I am installing the App.

Comment: this blog http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.com/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html says that I have to MANUALLY copy my APK expansion file to my phone, geez I hope the users of my App will able to do this.  I had to create the directory `/mnt/sdcard` on my phone before I copied the APK expansion file there.

Comment: As I'm sure you read in the expansion file guide, Google Play will automatically download the expansion file onto a user's device when they download it from Google Play (and, as they note, your app should double check and re-download from Google Play if necessary). There's no manual download process for end users.

Comment: @ianhanniballake When I looked into my device (nexus 7) under the folder of /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb, I found nothing. However, under the /mnt/sdcard/Android/data, I did find some folders with Java-like package names.

Comment: @JackWM - you need to manually create the folder on test devices - it is only automatically created when the app is downloaded from Google Play.